# CDF plot of 3D np.array()

Tags: python, numpy, plot, cdf

I have three np arrays with the following shapes:

```py
# (176 x 104)  
mean_displacement

# (176 x 104 x 15) 15 values for each displacement
displacement_distribution

# (176 x 104 x 15) 15 weights/probability for each displacement
weights
```

Now I want to compute its `CDF` but I'm having trouble since it is my first time working with multidimensional arrays. The CDF has to be computed for all displacements, for each pixel. There will be 18,304 pixels in and the `CDF` plot is within this area:

```py
(displacement[range(136, 163), :][:, range(0, 18)]) if displacement >= 0.1
```

That removes all cells with displacement less than `0.1` from the plot.

Just need some insight and here is [a Google drive link for the three np array files](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1qojrQc_KgaXcI_ImZi3sMgCHnpfxbVnV?usp=sharing) and a sample below:

```py
>>> weights
[
    [[0.123704][0.092778][0.092778][0.092778]]
    [[0.123704][0.092778][0.092778][0.092778]]
    [[0.123704][0.123704][0.123704][0.123704]]
    ...
]

>>> displacement_distribution
[
    [[0.1][0.1][0.1][0.1]]
    [[0.1][0.1][0.1][0.1]]
    ...
]
```

Here is a sketch of what the `CDF` plot should look like:

[image]

Comment: Can you show how is the CDF defined with respect to `mean_displacement`, `displacement_distribution`, and `weights`. In the 1D case, these would be one scalar, and two 15-elements vectors respectively, correct?

Comment: `mean_displacement` shows the mean displacement per cell/pixel,
`displacement_distribution`: for each pixel, there are 15 values of displacements
`weights`: for each pixel, there are 15 probabilities/weights associated with each of the 15 values of displacement

Comment: <img src="https://imgur.com/a/ZotBUGo">

Comment: Could you provide some sample data?

Comment: where can i send the numpy array files to you?

Comment: Try to take a sample and put in the question above so we can have a minimal reproducible setup.

Comment: [Google drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1qojrQc_KgaXcI_ImZi3sMgCHnpfxbVnV?usp=sharing)

Comment: i've edited the post and would it be ok if you could view the actual files and guide me a bit in detail?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what `mean_displacement` refers to here, does it correspond to the red curve on your plot?

Comment: The CDF has to be computed for all displacements for each pixel, there will be 18,304 in and the plot the CDF is within this area `(displacement[range(136,163), :][:,range(0,18)]) if displacement >= 0.1`. That is remove all cells with displacement less than 0.1 from the plot

Comment: the mean is the part of the threshold 0.1-15 and not a part of the CDF

Answer (score 1):

Here's pandas one-liner I came up with once. You can perhaps use it for each column in a loop.

```
import scipy.stats as sst
import numpy as np, pandas as pd 
#dummy data
distr=sst.beta(12,12)
values=distr.rvs(50)


cdf=pd.Series(np.ones(values.shape[0])/values.shape[0], index=values).sort_index().cumsum()
```

Here's visual test with example of plotting multiple cdf on one chart in pandas.

```
distr=sst.beta(12,12)
values=distr.rvs(20000)

cdf20k=pd.Series(np.ones(values.shape[0])/values.shape[0], index=values).sort_index().cumsum()

values=distr.rvs(50)
cdf50=pd.Series(np.ones(values.shape[0])/values.shape[0], index=values).sort_index().cumsum()

pd.DataFrame({
'theo':pd.Series(distr.cdf(np.arange(0,1,0.001)),np.arange(0,1,0.001)),
'empirical_20k_samples': cdf20k,
'empirical_50_samples': cdf50,
    }).fillna(method='ffill').plot()
```

[image]

Comment: yes `CDF` is cumulative distribution function, I tried your one liner but it just gave a straight line from 0-176 (row len)

Comment: Function I've send you is meant to calculate cdf of data in values table. It will give straight line if e.g. samples have uniform distribution over interval.